# rsync --delete fully understanding the correctly syntax to preserve the source directories and sync files with the destination directory

Tags: command-line, rsync

I'm running this command:

```
rsync -av --dry-run /home/acnt/public_html/_private/database/static/categories/temp/ --delete-after /home/acnt/public_html/_private/database/static/categories/
```

In my many tests it doesn't keep the temp directory, it removes all files and the entire directory tree, all other directories under the categories tree.

```
/home/acnt/public_html/_private/database/static/categories/
/home/acnt/public_html/_private/database/static/categories/temp
/home/acnt/public_html/_private/database/static/categories/dir1
/home/acnt/public_html/_private/database/static/categories/dir1/temp
/home/acnt/public_html/_private/database/static/categories/dir2
/home/acnt/public_html/_private/database/static/categories/dir2/temp
```

I want to preserve these directories under categories, but have failed to get the syntax correct.

What I'm after is a way to sync my temp directory contents `/home/acnt/public_html/_private/database/static/categories/temp/` with `/home/acnt/public_html/_private/database/static/categories/` and remove files in `/home/acnt/public_html/_private/database/static/categories/` that are not found in `/home/acnt/public_html/_private/database/static/categories/temp/`.

I wonder if I'm able to use rsync this way or if my tree structure is the issue here.

Comment: You are aware that `.../categories/temp` is a subdirectory of `.../categories`? What `rsync` is doing is removing the `temp` directory since there is no such directory in the source directory (`.../categories/temp/temp` does not exist).  It is doing what you have told it to do.

Comment: @Kusalananda That is what I was thinking, the tree structure is the issue, in this case? Is there any way to avoid losing the source tree folders and only update the destination with the source but remove orphans found in the destination that are not in the source? Thanks, lots to learn here. Most grateful.

Comment: The issue is that the destination _includes the source_. To update the destination therefore means updating the source. If you could move `temp` away, you would have no issues using it as the source without modifying it as part of the destination.

Comment: @Kusalananda ok that is very helpful, glad to see I was thinking the same.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your target directory *contains* the source directory.  The source directory is being modified (deleted) since it's part of the target directory hierarchy (and because it, obviously, does not contain *itself*).

To solve this, I would suggest moving `.../categories/temp` (your source directory) away to some place outside of `.../categories` (your target directory).  That way, the source directory would not be modified due to being part of the target hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you really want to copy from the `temp` directory that is inside your target, you need to tell `rsync` not to delete that subtree from the destination.

In this instance, the excluded directory tree is `temp` at the top of the destination tree, so `/temp`. To tell `rsync` that we want to exclude a directory rather than a file we suffix with `/`, so the final exclusion becomes `/temp/`.

```
base=/home/acnt/public_html/_private/database/static/categories
rsync --dry-run -av --delete-after --exclude '/temp/' "$base/temp/" "$base/"
```

I've used `$base` simply to keep the paths shorter so that the solution is clearer.

Comment: Seemly many ways to do the same. This is what I was after, I did not understand the full syntax, very helpful, thank you so much.